# Rejected app No full-size app banner for Android TV on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, android-tv

I tried to submit an app for Android TV on Google Play, my app is rejected

**No full-size app banner
Your app does not contain a full-size app banner or is it not visible in the launcher. We are targeting 1080P, which we consider xhdpi. Apps should include the banner in the xhdpi (320 dpi) drawables folder with a size of (320px × 180px). Please refer to our Home Screen Banner and UI Patterns documentation.
The title should help users identify apps in the launcher. Please refer to our Visual Design and User Interaction documentation for more information.
For example, your banner does not fill the entire banner space.**

I added banner in Manifest File and my banner png file in drawabletxhdpi and it's dimension 320 x 180 png, but always rejected for android Tv from Google Play how can I fix my application to be accepted from GooglePlay

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.kocsistem.pixageoneandroid">

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.software.leanback"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:targetApi="m"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
        android:name=".view.CustomApplication"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:banner="@drawable/logo_tv">

        <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <receiver android:name=".view.download.DownloadPublish">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="MyAction" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name=".network.broadcast.StartActivityBootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".network.service.ScheduleChecker"
            android:enabled="true" />


    </application>

    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="720"
        tools:ignore="ManifestOrder" />

</manifest>
```

banner with text same the android label name

[image]

Comment: If your 320x180 icon banner is just an image without text, add the name of your app to it. On TV the "app name" string isn't shown consistently? in TV home screen. [Found possible solution in a different forum, do post if correct answer]. See: https://developer.android.com/docs/quality-guidelines/tv-app-quality test TV-BN.

Comment: My banner is text same the application name, I added above

Comment: Just a guess, but if the background of your banner is transparent, maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Old question I know, but I'm having the same issue (not transparent background). How did you fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that the background color is not transparent, and banner should be contain project name of your application.